# That is possible to add '' in execute statement (PSQL)

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to run in postgresql that statement

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION dynamic_update(nazwa_t text,index int,nazwa_k text, war text )
    RETURNS void LANGUAGE PLPGSQL AS $$
BEGIN
    EXECUTE 'UPDATE schemat.' || $1 || ' set ' || $3 || ' = ' || $4  || ' where id = ' || $2 || ' ;';
END
$$;
```

but i have problem because execute without '' on 4 argument, anyone know how to trick this ? I try everything what i know and still stay in dead point. I will be gratefull for any help :)

Comment: What is the postgresql version?

Comment: you're basically opening an [SQL injection attack](http://bobby-tables.com)
 hole. You should NOT be using this.

Comment: I just learn, thanks for telling me that at now i will be safe to don't do this again...

Answer (score 1):

There are [quoting functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-OTHER) that you can use in these situations, in particular:

> `quote_ident(string text)`
>   Return the given string suitably quoted to be used as an identifier in an SQL statement string.

and

> `quote_literal(string text)`
>   Return the given string suitably quoted to be used as a string literal in an SQL statement string. Embedded single-quotes and backslashes are properly doubled. Note that `quote_literal` returns null on null input; if the argument might be null, `quote_nullable` is often more suitable.

There's also a `quote_literal` that works with non-text values.

So you can safely say this:

```
EXECUTE 'UPDATE schemat.' || quote_ident($1) || ' set ' || quote_ident($3) || ' = ' || quote_literal($4)  || ' where id = ' || quote_literal($2) || ' ;';
```

If you're expecting `$2` to be NULL then, as noted in the `quote_literal` documentation, use `quote_nullable` instead.